# How to include child elements directly in xsl template

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I have a template that shows waypoints from a gpx file. Currently, the only way I can add child elements to the item is to use a template. Is there a way that I can get the value of child elements without using a separate template? So that instead of doing:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="gpx:link" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

I could do something like:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="child@href" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Here is the xml and xsl that I use for it.

```
<wpt lat="00.00000000" lon="00.00000000">
    <ele>600</ele>
    <time>2015-02-16T06:12:27Z</time>
    <name><![CDATA[Photo]]></name>
    <link href="2015-02-16_01-12-27.jpg">
        <text>2015-02-16_01-12-27.jpg</text>
    </link>
    <sat>0</sat>
</wpt>

<xsl:template name="wpt-circle">
  <xsl:for-each select="gpx:wpt">
    <circle stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" r="6">
      <xsl:call-template name="latlonc">
        <xsl:with-param name="lon" select="@lon"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="lat" select="@lat"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:attribute name="text">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gpx:name" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gpx:link" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </circle>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gpx:name">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gpx:link">
  <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

They syntax you are looking for is this

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="gpx:link/@href" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

You can use any XPath expression in the select parameter here, not just a single child node.

In fact, you can also do this...

```
<circle stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" r="6" href="{gpx:link/@href}">
```

This is known as [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), with the curly braces `{}` indicating an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.